# How can we set default property value in Spring Boot in a Common project?

Tags: spring-boot, properties-file

So we have moved the components and services that are common between our company's applications to a separate project, e.g. JsonCommon. In the common project features are also separated by assigning a spring profile name, so for example application A need only to activate those profiles of the features it needs.

In the common project, some properties are feature related but there are also properties that we simply renamed it from spring ones to make it more readable.

For example:

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=${xyz.messagebroker.env.host}
spring.rabbitmq.port=${xyz.messagebroker.env.port}
spring.rabbitmq.username=${xyz.messagebroker.env.username}
spring.rabbitmq.password=${xyz.messagebroker.env.password}
```

So in application A you will need to set xyz.messagebroker.** properties rather than spring.rabbitmq.**

Note that these properties are only used when messagebroker profile is active.

Now if in application A there is no **application-messagebroker.properties** then I get error because ***xyz.messagebroker*** properties are not set

If I move these properties in the common project to **application-messagebroker.properties**, then if the profile is active in app A, we will have 2 properties in classpath with the same name and I don't know in what order spring boot is loading the two so one may override the others (this is because we also set default values in the common project in case the profile is active but properties haven't been set)

Any suggestion or best practice is appreciated.

Comment: Any suggestion?